# In Slack, how can I run a Hubot script when a new user joins for the first time

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, slack-api, hubot, slack

I know you can do

```
robot.enter (res) ->
  res.send "Welcome to the channel!"
```

But that will run whenever someone joins. I only want this to run if it is the first time a user has joined the room. Is there a way to check for this? Thanks!

Comment: Log out the `res` object. Do you see anything to identify the user? If so, you can add that to an array somewhere. If the identifier is not in the array, you know this is the first time they logged in.

Comment: You can do a call back with `robot.emit` to run whatever script you want.